# Wrong exception message thrown by npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

My database script is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE books
(
    book_name national character varying(50) not null primary key
);
```

When I try following code in c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) SELECT NULL;";
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            npgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

}
```

It gives me this type of error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in Npgsql.dll
>
> Additional information: Backend sent unrecognized response type: _

I know I am passing **NULL** value in **NOT NULL** column. I want to get the exact error message. What the hell does the above error means?

Comment: Are you just by chance using PostgreSQL 9.3? It is well known (in the mailing list) that all but the most recent version of Npgsql will throw some wrong exceptions and behave strangely with this version of PostgreSQL. I had some problems like ours myself.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: look at your connection string.  You may be passing in an unsupported option there.  Double check and cross reference with [this page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/).